# Child routes not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying out nested routes in my reactjs application. I have 3 child routes of Route "NewHome". This is how my route structure looks

```
 <Route path='/app' onEnter={hasAuth}>
                    <IndexRoute component={NewHome}>
                        <IndexRoute component={Reviews}/>
                        <Route>
                            <Route path={"/reviews"} component={Reviews}/>
                            <Route path={"/search"} component={Search}/>
                            <Route path={'/user-profile-page'} component={UserProfilePage}/>
                        </Route>
                    </IndexRoute>
```

So when I load my application, the first page which comes is /app. In this I see NewHome getting rendered, which is expected. In this NewHome, "Reviews" is not getting shown/rendered, which is the index route.

**What I want:** I want the reviews to be the default/first views in NewHome. I have a profile picture in my header. When I click on that, the reviews should take me to the /user-profile-page' route. I have  attached the required method to onclick of that picture like this

```
to_profile_page(){
        this.context.router.push('/user-profile-page')
    }
```

**Result:** Reviews is not getting rendered. Also, When I click on profile picture, the url changes from /app to /user-profile-page for a fraction of second and then again get back to /app. I am not able to see my profile page.

This is my NewHome

```
class NewHomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={c.container}>
                <div className="page-content-wrapper full-height">
                    {/*<!-- START PAGE CONTENT -->*/}
                    <div className="content full-height">
                        <div className="container-fluid container-fluid-media full-height no-padding">
                            <div className="row full-height no-margin">
                                <NewSidebar/>
                                {this.props.children}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default withStyles(c)(NewHomePage)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The syntax you use doesn't match with `react-router v4`. Are you sure you are using v4

Comment: I am using react-router 2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing it to this **[github issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1950)**, it seems that nesting IndexRoute is not allowed, you could instead restructure your routes  like

```
<Route path='/app' onEnter={hasAuth}>
   <Route component={NewHome}>
      <IndexRoute component={Reviews}/>
      <Route>
          <Route path={"/reviews"} component={Reviews}/>
          <Route path={"/search"} component={Search}/>
          <Route path={'/user-profile-page'} component={UserProfilePage}/>
      </Route>
   </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: But I need NewHome as index route

Comment: so doesn't it load if you configure like above

Comment: You have removed NewHome as IndexRoute. I am wondering how will it load NewHome as default. There are other routes also on NewHome level.

Comment: That because the Route with NewHome isn't given a path